# NextJS API route ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (no middleware)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

I've been struggling to solve this problem for ages.

Occasionally my API routes calls are infinitely redirected and end up with error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. The only solution is to open the API URL manually, for a while the browser shows the redirect error, but after a few seconds, it successfully opens the API URL, and after that also the normal XHR API calls from the front end for a given URL start working again. Then the error repeats randomly after a few days. Every API URL must be "repaired" manually separately.

I've been searching all related information, but mostly when people had similar errors, they were using middleware and the error was happening consistently. For me, it happens once a day on localhost and once a week on Vercel production for my customers (which is really bad).

I have this same problem in NextJS v12.1.4 with /pages and NextJS v14.1.0 with /app folder.

I think that maybe something is wrong with Next itself, but I have no idea how to find the solution. When this error is happening, the actual API route is not even reached (I've tried to put console.log into GET, which normally is shown in the console, but when it's being infinitely redirected, it happens even before the request hits the route. It is strange.

I've tried to add "trailingSlash: true" to next.config.js, no help. Maybe I could somehow disable caching on these API requests? They need to be fresh anyway.

[image]
[image]

The API route code:

```
import { query, table } from "../backend/db"; // knex function

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    const contentPages = await getContentPages();

    return res.status(200).json({ result: true, contentPages });
  }
}

async function getContentPages() {
  try {
    const contentPages = await query(table("pages").select());

    return contentPages;
  } catch (e) {
    return { error: true };
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    scrollRestoration: true,
  },

  reactStrictMode: false,
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  output: "export",
  trailingSlash: true,
  exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      "/k2/": {
        page: "/k2",
      },
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The issue should be in your backend. Please send more info about that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information. I've put the image because it's impossible to copy the redirect error as text so that it is clearly visible what is happening and maybe someone finds out more from the image. Also I've given info about Next versions and that the error happens only occasionally, which makes it super strange. Apart from that, I don't know what else I could post here. Maybe if you had some tip how to investigate this issue more...

Comment: Maybe try and explain what is happening in ur backend

Comment: It looks like content_pages redirects to content_pages/ and vice versa.  And  the browser caches those redirects.  I would guess that clearing browser cache also “fixes” it.  Are you doing any redirects on purpose in your app?  Or url rewriting?

Comment: I've added the API route code and next.config.js to the text. No I'm not doing any redirects on purpose at all. Definitely no "308" code in my whole project.

Comment: It’s not ideal but you could add a random or date param to the xhr url query string so it’s never from cache aka cache busting

Comment: And yes, exactly, clearing browser cache also fixes it. But I cannot do this somehow on purpose, so it doesn't help much. Hm adding a random string to the URL really could help, but I'd still prefer another solution, if there was any chance.. At least disable caching on NextJs level or something. But good point! I am using useSwr() on frontend, so having the same URL is beneficial for caching by this package on frontend side.. But I could solve this with custom fetcher actually if it is the only way.

Comment: If you flipped the setting of [trailingSlash](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/trailingSlash) I could see this happening maybe

Comment: Yeah, maybe, but I've tried all three options (no, false, true), also putting the API URL with and without slash and the redirects are still happening. But maybe after resetting cache it could be ok, but I cannot try it since the error will happen next time maybe in a day. But it doesn't repair it immediately, but maybe it's not possible.